# Azure DevOps - schedule release deployment is not available

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, release

In Azure DevOps you can schedule a release as many times as possible. In my example, I want to create a release 3 times a day Monday - Friday

[image]

But, if I need to actually deploy those releases 3 times a day Monday - Friday, I can't. There is only one slot available and user can't add more.

Is this a limitation of Azure DevOps and how I can actually deploy my release (not create them) 3 times a day?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not available at present.

Not sure if totally got your point, what you are looking for is something similar to schedule redeploy.

When you submit a pre-deployment approval for a stage, you can defer the deployment until a specified time. You could not select or specify multiple times here.

You could submit a feature request in Develop Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick pointed out, this currently isn't possible. You can set multiple schedules for a release but individual stages can't be scheduled more than once. As a workaround, you could clone the stage and then set different schedules for it.